# Matplotlib multiple `plot_surface`s, how do you get proper occlusion of surfaces?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, scientific-computing, occlusion

I have two Matplotlib `plot_surface`s that intersect. For example, two spheres that are close enough to intersect.

When I use the mouse to move the camera angle, I expect proper occlusion (I.e. not to see the parts of the sphere that are hidden by the occlusion).

Instead I am stuck seeing one object always fully rendered on top of the other.

**I need to render png files for an important presentation. But with the current occlusion being so wrong... I can't use any screenshots.**

**How do you get proper occlusion of surfaces?**

Does non interactive backends and renderers do occlusion correctly? (If yes, then that would be a way-forward. Albeit a non-ideal and inelegant way-forward... but at least I can save pictures of the figure that would be usable in my presentation by programmatically setting the camera's elevation and azimuth and camer center.)

---

Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# from: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo2.py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

x = 1 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = 1 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = 1 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b')
# modification from original code
ax.plot_surface(x+1.5, y, z, rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b')

plt.show()
```

screenshots:

[image]

[image]

for some reason when you rotate the camera's azimuth this causes one object to be painted on top of the other. these two screen shots demonstrate azimuth -88 degrees and then -92 degrees. so maybe the issue is the -90 degrees. OR maybe whatever `plot_surface` object that has a center that is closer to the camera gets rendered on top of the other object.

Comment: You may use transparency (alpha < 1)? this does not solve the problem but at least the illusion of intersection between the surfaces looks better.